# Search pattern using pcregrep

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have following patterns in a text file.

```
######################
# ADD=123 New Comment
######################

if ($ADD==123)
```

Out of this, the following lines are variable

```
# ADD=124 Old Comment

if ($ADD==1234)
```

I tried pcregrep for multiline greping, but I am not good with regex. Any pointers how to extract this patterns.

```
[root@srv admin]# pcregrep -M '######################\n#*\n' text.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -n '/###[#]*/,/if (\$ADD/{p}' input
```

Comment: My output should be like

######################
# ADD=123 New Comment
######################

if ($ADD==123)


this regex displays a whole lot of other things.

Answer (score 1):

```
pcregrep -Mo '(?<=#)\s*ADD=1234' text.php
```

pcregrep -multiline -only, look behind(to find the last #), then any number of spaces, then 'ADD=1234'(or you can do 'ADD=[[:digit:]]*')

hope this helps